# I am making a pygame version of galaga. There is a weird error(see below)

Tags: python, oop, pygame

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Lucas/PycharmProjects/FirstPyGame/Main.py", line 117, in <module>
    player.changespeed(3, 0)
  File "C:/Users/Lucas/PycharmProjects/FirstPyGame/Main.py", line 42, in changespeed
    self.change_x += x
AttributeError: 'Ship' object has no attribute 'change_x'
```

Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 255, 255)
size = [800, 600]
x_coord = 400
y_coord = 600
x_speed = 0
y_speed = 0
font = pygame.font.SysFont("Calibri", 25, True, False)

snow_list = []

for i in range(50):
    x = random.randrange(0, 800)
    y = random.randrange(0, 600)
    snow_list.append([x, y])

pygame.display.set_caption("Star Fighter")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


class Ship(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def ___init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__()

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0

    def changespeed(self, x, y):
        self.change_x += x
        self.change_y += y

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.change_x
        self.rect.y += self.change_y

    def DrawShip(screen, x, y):
        a = pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, ((x_coord - 5), (y_coord - 60), 10, 10))
        b = pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, ((x_coord - 15), (y_coord - 50), 10, 10))
        c = pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, ((x_coord - 5), (y_coord - 50), 10, 10))
        d = pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, ((x_coord + 5), (y_coord - 50), 10, 10))

class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, color):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([20, 15])
        self.image.fill(color)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def ScrollStars():
        for i in range(len(snow_list)):
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, WHITE, snow_list[i], 3)
            snow_list[i][1] += 1
            if snow_list[i][1] > 600:
                y = random.randrange(-50, -10)
                snow_list[i][1] = y
                x = random.randrange(0, 800)
                snow_list[i][0] = x

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([4, 10])
        self.image.fill(WHITE)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y -= 3


all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

for i in range(50):
    # This represents a block
    block = Block(BLUE)

    # Set a random location for the block
    block.rect.x = random.randrange(800)
    block.rect.y = random.randrange(300)

    # Add the block to the list of objects
    block_list.add(block)
    all_sprites_list.add(block)

score = 0
player = Ship()

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.changespeed(-3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.changespeed(3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                bullet = Bullet()
                bullet.rect.x = x_coord
                bullet.rect.y = 550
                all_sprites_list.add(bullet)
                bullet_list.add(bullet)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_q:
                running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.changespeed(3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.changespeed(-3, 0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_speed = 0
            if event.type == pygame.K_UP or pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_speed = 0

    for bullet in bullet_list:
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, block_list, True)

        for block in block_hit_list:
            bullet_list.remove(bullet)
            all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
            score += 1

        if bullet.rect.y < -10:
            bullet_list.remove(bullet)
            all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)

    x_coord = x_coord + x_speed
    y_coord = y_coord + y_speed

    all_sprites_list.update()

    screen.fill(BLACK)
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
    Ship.DrawShip(screen, x_coord, y_coord)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(70)
pygame.quit()
```

Could someone explain the error that I am having? I am a beginner and I do not understand it very well. It says that the Ship class has no attribute 'change_x' but it does, right? Sorry if this doesn't make any sense, but someone please help me with this. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: There are three underscores in the beginning of `__init__`, should be two.

Comment: @KlausD. good catch. I was really confused why the instantiation worked even though no args were passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by a typo. The name of the constructor is `__init__` rather than `___init__`:

<s>`def ___init__(self, x, y):`</s>

```py
def __init__(self, x, y):
```